# Issue related to UICollectionView cell selection when invalidate its layout

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a simple screen with two collection views. What I want is that when I select one item in the first CV, I want to show a selection indicator and show this item multiple times in the second CV, like shown in the following screenshot (ignore the transparency in the image):

[image]

Here is my code (It's a bit long but it's very simple):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var cv1: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var cv2: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        cv1.dataSource = self
        cv1.delegate = self
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        let layout = cv1.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
        var size = layout.itemSize
        size.width = cv1.bounds.width / CGFloat(items.count)
        layout.itemSize = size
        layout.invalidateLayout()
        cv1.reloadData()
    }

    let items = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "E", "H", "I"]

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

        cell.setText(collectionView == cv1 ? items[indexPath.row] : items[currentSelection])           

        return cell
    }

    var currentSelection = -1

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if currentSelection != -1 {
            let oldCell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: currentSelection, inSection: 0)) as? CollectionViewCell

            oldCell?.makeSelect(false)
        }

        var shouldSelect = true

        if indexPath.row != currentSelection {
            currentSelection = indexPath.row
        }
        else {
            currentSelection = -1
            shouldSelect = false
        }

        let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? CollectionViewCell
        cell?.makeSelect(shouldSelect)

        // if you comment the block of code bellow the selection works fine
        if collectionView == cv1 {
            if shouldSelect {
                cv2.dataSource = self
                cv2.delegate = self
                cv2.reloadData()
                cv2.alpha = 1
            }
            else {
                cv2.dataSource = nil
                cv2.delegate = nil
                cv2.alpha = 0
            }
        }
    }
}

class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    func setText(str: String) {
        label.text = str
    }

    func makeSelect(selected: Bool) {
        contentView.backgroundColor = selected ? UIColor.yellowColor() : UIColor.clearColor()
    }
}
```

The problem is that when you run the project and select the cell with the letter D, what happens is this:

[image]

If inside the method `viewDidLayoutSubviews` you remove the following line, all works fine:

```
cv1.reloadData()
```

However, in my real project I need to call the `reloadData()` function in this place.

I think that the problem isn't this call because if you comment the block marked in the code, the one that made the second collection view appear, you will see that the selection in the first collection view works fine without removing the `reloadData()` call. The problem also appears if you use different reuse identifiers for the cells.

My question is: What is going on here?

Comment: Do you really have to reload the collection view in "viewDidLayoutSubviews"? Can you just invalidate the layout instead?

Comment: @almas The problem is that in the real project where I have this issue I apply a transparency to some cells. It works ok in the iPhone but in iPad doesn't work, the only way in which I managed to make it work was calling the reloadData function. I have solved the issue related to the transparency in the iPad, but I want to know why this behavior occurs.

Comment: I think in this case you need to fix your transparency issue first. Reloading the data in "viewDidLayoutSubviews" doesn't make sense. If you absolutely have to do that, then you can just remember the index of the selected cell, reload data, and select that cell programmatically again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things happening here:

Before start, according to [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewdatasource#//apple_ref/swift/intf/c:objc(pl)UICollectionViewDataSource):

> The collection view’s data source object provides both the content for
>   items and the views used to present that content. When the collection
>   view **first loads** its content, it asks its data source to provide a
>   **view** for each visible item.
>
> To simplify the creation process for your code, the collection view
>   requires that you always dequeue views, rather than create them
>   explicitly in your code. There are two methods for dequeueing views.
>   The one you use depends on which type of view has been requested:
>
> - dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:for:).
> - dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind:withReuseIdentifier:for:).

Now, lets see how your code executes:

When the app starts, you have a collection view (`cv1`) showing letters from A to I with a blue background.

If you tap over any cell `collectionView(collectionView:, didSelectItemAtIndexPath: )` is triggered, here you change the color of the cell: `cell?.makeSelect(shouldSelect)`. Later, at some point in this function you set the datasource for `cv2`: `cv2.dataSource = self`

The first time the datasource is set on the second collection view, new instances of `CollectionViewCell` are created, so `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is invoked, but in this function you are calling `cv1.reloadData()`.

This call will make the cells in `cv1` to be reused and the cell you previously changed the color will be probably used for another letter (this is why you see another letter selected).

This only happens the first time because after that, cells in `cv2` are already created and reused, so `viewDidLayoutSubviews` isn't invoked.

A quick fix is set the datasource to the second collection view (`cv2`) in `ViewDidLoad` as you are doing with `cv1`:

```
cv2.dataSource = self
cv2.delegate = self
```

This will create new instances of `CollectionViewCell`, so when you reset the datasource for `cv2` in `collectionView(collectionView: , didSelectItemAtIndexPath:)` cell will be already created and `viewDidLayoutSubviews` wont be triggered.

Ok, this is just a workaround and doesn't really solve the problem, if for any reason a new cell is created the problem will occur again.

The right way to solve this is prepare the cells for reuse and reselect the current value, something like this:

```
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    ...

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()

        contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        label?.text = nil
    }
}
```

And, in `collectionView(collectionView:, cellForItemAtIndexPath: )`:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    ...

    if collectionView == cv1 && indexPath.row == currentSelection {
        cell.makeSelect(true)
    }

    return cell
}
```